# Any way to have "Open Declaration" in Eclipse move to the autowired service?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, autowired

Getting started with a new project that is heavily reliant on Spring. There are lots of services that are autowired and I loathe the repetitive task of using the "Open Declaration" command on an Interface service and having to navigate to the implementing class to find the method. Is there an easier way to do this?

On a side note- every single one of these multitudinous service interfaces have one implementing service and I've never understood the reasoning or benefit behind this architecture model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the type or method declaration (e.g. the name) and hit CTRL-T for the hierarchy. It works backwards as well (CTRL-T twice) to find super classes.